# How to troubleshoot threads leak?

Tags: java, multithreading, jvm, out-of-memory

Currently I have an application suffering from serious threads leak but I can't find the source of the threads based on the stack. How do I solve this problem? The thread stack is like this:

```
"OkHttp ConnectionPool" #1759 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f5fc440f000 nid=0x34ab0 in Object.wait() [0x00007f5eef0ef000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (on object monitor)
        at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
        - waiting on <0x00000007b233c660> (a okhttp3.ConnectionPool)
        at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:460)
        at okhttp3.ConnectionPool$1.run(ConnectionPool.java:67)
        - locked <0x00000007b233c660> (a okhttp3.ConnectionPool)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: Can you explain what you mean  "suffering from thread leaks"? What are the side effects? Is it throwing an error?

Comment: I guess just huge amounts of threads?

Comment: There are a couple errors that can happen from leaking threads in an application container. (1) PermGen error implies leaked threads not being GC'd (2) OOM native thread error implies too many threads being created.